# Kotlin build error in Android Studio on << intent.putExtra("string", it.getString("string") >>

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I can't figure out what's wrong with the following piece of code. Seems to me getString necessarily returns a String. In fact, it works on the lines above! Is this a bug?

```
fun loadExtraBundleIntoIntent(origIntent: Intent, resultIntent: Intent) {
    origIntent.extras?.let {
        if (it.getString("peerUid") != null) {
            resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", "ChatFragment")
            resultIntent.putExtra("peerUid", it.getString("peerUid"))
        } else if (it.getString("fragment") != null) {
            resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", it.getString("fragment"))
        }

        if (it.getString("action") != null)
            resultIntent.putExtra("action", it.getString("action"))
    }
}
```

Error on

```
resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", it.getString("fragment"))
```

Error message:

```
Error:(80, 30) Overload resolution ambiguity:
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Bundle!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Parcelable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Serializable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) Parcelable!>!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) CharSequence!>!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) String!>!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Boolean): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: BooleanArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Byte): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: ByteArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Char): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: CharArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: CharSequence!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Double): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: DoubleArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Float): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: FloatArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Int): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: IntArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Long): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: LongArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Short): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: ShortArray!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: String!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdVDI.png)

Comment: I filled in a bug report on Kotlin's tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19139

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It considers that the value returned from `it.getString ("fragment")` is null and the null value matches with all these `putExtra` functions.

> e.g: `resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", null)`
>
> Bundle, Parcelable, Serializable, Parcelable, CharSequence, String, BooleanArray, ByteArray, CharArray, CharSequence, DoubleArray, FloatArray, IntArray, LongArray, ShortArray, String
>
> all these parameters are objects and null can be set into all these parameters - *"Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match"*

Somehow the compiler is considering that **"it"** value can be null after `'else if'` and this should not happen because it is a type `Bundle!` non-null. I believe this is a compiler bug.

I have tested with the following kotlin version to compile your code:

- **1.1.3** (released on June 23, 2017): kotlin build error.
- **1.1.2** (released on April 25, 2017): kotlin build error.
- **1.0.7** (released on March 15, 2017): compile! without error!

Then, If you use the version **1.0.7**, it will work! - It's hard to set up this version in the Android studio.
Or you can use other options to force the compiler to avoid/fix this problem, for example:

- `'!!'`: `it!!.getString("fragment")`
- cast to `String`: `it.getString("fragment") as String`
- `?: ""`: it.getString("fragment") ?: ""
- etc...

Comment: Thanks, "it" being null makes perfect sense with the error message. However I judged that there was no way "it" could be "null". Indeed, see my own answer below: the problem was there is no "else if" in Kotlin, which is weird but it is what it is, hence the error: an obscured syntax error.

Comment: I was WRONG, there IS a "else if" in Kotlin. So, I still don't know the cause of the error. Seems to me like a compiler bug.

I don't think "it.getString("string")" can be null. Can it? If so, why is it that no error triggers in the first "if block" but it triggers in the "else if" block?

Comment: Thanks for testing with different Kotlin versions, Victor. Indeed it definitely is a compiler bug. I will report your findings in the bug report I filled on Kotlin's issue tracker. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19139

Until it gets fixed, I will just explicitly (and redundantly) say it is a non-null type using the '!!' operator as you suggested.

Comment: Very good reporting this problem to Kotlin team.
So, Is this question answered? Or do you need some more information?

Comment: Sorry, It's answered.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a compiler bug. However, I would suggest you rewrite it in a way that you only retrieve each value once from the Bundle, so the compiler can infer that the putExtra() second argument is always non-null:

```
fun loadExtraBundleIntoIntent(origIntent: Intent, resultIntent: Intent) {
    origIntent.extras?.let {
        val peerUid = it.getString("peerUid")
        if (peerUid != null) {
            resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", "ChatFragment")
            resultIntent.putExtra("peerUid", peerUid)
        } else it.getString("fragment")?.let {
            resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", it)
        }

        it.getString("action")?.let {
            resultIntent.putExtra("action", it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should fill the value with noun-null value ...
if ur value is null u can not use it and take this error

LIKE :

```
 intent.putExtra("PRICE", txt_price)
```

u should pass Correct value LIKE :

```
  intent.putExtra("PRICE", product.price)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are putting multiple extras with the same key values. Here you use fragment as key value here

```
 resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", "ChatFragment")
```

and again here

```
resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", it.getString("fragment"))
```

Comment: That's intended. Because it was an "if {} else if {}" there was no way both lines of code could be ran in runtime - it's one or the other.

See my own answer below: the problem was there is no "else if" in Kotlin, which is weird but it is what it is, hence the error: an obscured syntax error.

Comment: Edit: I was wrong, there is an "else if" in kotlin, so I don't know what's causing the error. Looks like a compiler bug to me...